# Conversion to object .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem. I have a list of companies `List<Company>`

I need to write a method where I send that list and other lists like `List<store>` or `List<p>`...

The point is that I have tried using a method like 
`fillField(List<object> list)` but I get an error

> the company cannot be converted to object

My question is: do not all of the entities inherit from `object`?

How do I have to change the method?

Thank you

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Depending on what your `fillField` is doing, it might be possible to use a generic method like `fillField<T>(List<T> list) {}`

Comment: the point is I need to use polymorphism. this is the hint

Comment: Yes - `store` or `p` will inherit from `object` - but that doesn't mean that `List<store>` inherits from `List<object>` ...

Comment: We're not guessing off of "hints". Either tell us all relevant information or don't. That said, call the method like: `fillField(companyList.Cast<object>());` if you think that solves the problem.

Comment: @ marc_s and how can I make this two to inherit ?

Comment: The type system won't let you - because `fillField` might try to add a `new Albatross()` to a `List<object>` when in fact what you passed it was a `List<Company>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to learn about **[generics](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic)**. Essentially Generics are used for passing any type you want, such as when you want to **[serialize](http://blog.danskingdom.com/saving-and-loading-a-c-objects-data-to-an-xml-json-or-binary-file/)** (save) the object as a file.

An example on how to use generics:

```
public void SendListToOtherLists<T> (List<T> listYouWantToSend)
{
    // Your logic...
}
```

In that example you declared that it's a generic void (it will receive any type as a parameter), and in the parameters you declared that you want to pass a list of any type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all objects do inherit `object`, but you're getting that exception because `List<Company>` cannot be converted to `List<object>`. Unless you use `.Select` to convert `Company` list to the object list. You have to use a generic function with type parameters:

```
public void fillField(List<object> list)
```

Becomes:

```
public void fillField<T>(List<T> list)
```